# Laravel Eloquent collection of mixed models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have a database with a table called files. Within that, we have the following structure -

```
- id
- parent_id (nullable)
- name
- type (enum: File or Folder)
- created_at
- updated_at
```

I then have two models, one called `File` and one called `Folder`. `Folder` extends `File`. Is there a way that when I call `File::all(),` for example, I can utilize Eloquent to map the respective models based on the databases `type` field?

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort the files and folders so that files are nested under the folders they belong to?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Realised what you actually want is to populate them by type.

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent returns collection instances, so one way would be to call `map()` and have that return the appropriate objects for each item, eg, if it's a file just return the file, whereas if it's a folder populate a new `Folder` instance and return it.

Or you could have `File` and `Folder` be models that work off the same table, with global scopes used to limit the query set by type, then call `all()` on both of them and merge them.

But I think the best thing to do with them is make them a single model, that behaves differently based on the type. Put any differing functionality in methods on the model so it can be treated the same regardless of type by calling those methods. I think that's the safer option in that you're making your models polymorphic - they can be treated the same regardless of type.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the answer, I was able to find a solution in the meantime which works well for me!

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to work out the answer by extending Laravel Models `newFromBuilder` method.

Here is my class -

```php
class File {

    public static $types = ['File', 'Folder'];

     /**
     * Create a new model instance that is existing.
     *
     * @param array $attributes
     * @param null  $connection
     *
     * @return Model|string
     */
    public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
    {
        $model = $this->newInstanceFromType($attributes->type);

        $model->exists = true;

        $model->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes, true);

        $model->setConnection($connection ?: $this->getConnectionName());

        $model->fireModelEvent('retrieved', false);

        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Determine our model instance based on the type field.
     *
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function newInstanceFromType(string $type)
    {
        if (!in_array($type, static::$types)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('$type must be one of static::$types');
        }

        $model = 'App\Models\\' . $type;
        return new $model;
    }
}
```

This will then return either a `File` or `Folder` model instance depending on what the `type` enum is from the database.

Thanks all for the input!